# C++ code for task scheduling

Tags: c

This code has no errors but then when i execute it, there is no output and the program automatically shuts down saying the program has stopped working.

```
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
char *timetoken;
char currtime[7];
char schedtime[7];
int i;
struct tm *localtimeptr;
strcpy(schedtime,"15:25:00");
while(6!=9)
{
   time_t lt;
   sleep(1);
   lt = time(NULL);
   localtimeptr = localtime(lt);
   timetoken=strtok(asctime(localtimeptr)," ");
   for(i=1;i<5;i++)
   timetoken=strtok('\0'," ");
   if(i==3)
   {
           strcpy(currtime,timetoken);
    }
}
           printf("The current time is: %s\n",currtime);
           printf("We are waiting for: %s\n",schedtime);
           if(!strcmp(currtime,schedtime))
           {
                                          printf("Time to do stuff \n");
                                          system("C:\PROJECT X");
            }        
            getch();
            return 0;                      
}
```

Comment: What on earth is this doing here? `system("C:\PROJECT X");`

Comment: Also, you are copying 8 bytes into schedtime which was allocated for 7.

Comment: Why is this tagged `c` if its about `c++`? Which one is it?

Comment: @sarnold He likes chimpanzees?

Comment: @CaptainObvlious: Hey! I liked that movie too, as a wee lad... :)

Comment: @K-ballo he is using printf instead of cout if that makes you feel better. :)

Comment: 'for(i=1;i<5;i++) timetoken=strok('\0', " ");'?  What are you trying to do?

Comment: Thanks for sharing your story, but what's your question, and how will the answer be of interest of anyone else after today? [Stack Overflow is not a debugging service.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135066/33732)

Comment: @Milan: If the OP wanted to know about C, he would have asked about C, not C++.  Don't remove the C++ tag just because he doesn't write C++ the way you would write C++.

Comment: if this code has no errors, I'd hate to think what code with errors does look like :/

Comment: @Benjamin Lindley Now that the OP himself re-tagged, My guess that C code without any C++ parts is indeed a C code, seems correct.

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure what you're trying to do, but this is fishy:

```
while(6!=9)
{
   /* ... */
}
/* ... more code ... */
```

6 will always not equal 9, so this is an infinite loop.  There's no way to break out of the loop, and so nothing in the "more code" section will execute.  This means that your `printf`s won't execute, nor will your `system` call.  You need some way out of this loop.

To make the code easier to read (*which should always be a top priority!*), I would suggest just writing

```
while (true) {
    ...
}
```

to make it clearer that the loop is supposed to run until you explicitly `break` from it.

Another note: this code

```
system("C:\PROJECT X");
```

Is incorrect, because C++ will interpret `\P` as an escape character.  To fix this, escape your slash:

```
system("C:\\PROJECT X");
```

For another bug, look closely at this loop:

```
   for(i=1;i<5;i++)
   timetoken=strtok('\0'," ");
   if(i==3)
   {
       strcpy(currtime,timetoken);
   }
```

C++ is interpreting this as

```
   for(i=1;i<5;i++) {
       timetoken=strtok('\0'," ");
   }

   if(i==3)
   {
       strcpy(currtime,timetoken);
   }
```

From here it's clearer that this won't work, since the `if` statement is outside the loop.  Consequently, `i` is never 3.  You probably meant

```
   for(i=1;i<5;i++) {
       timetoken=strtok('\0'," ");
       if(i==3)
       {
           strcpy(currtime,timetoken);
       }
   }
```

Making the effort to clean up your code formatting (indentation, whitespace, etc.) will help prevent this sort of error.  If you had declared `i` as local to the for loop, then you probably would have spotted this earlier.  For example, this code doesn't compile:

```
   for(int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
       timetoken=strtok('\0'," ");
   }

   if(i==3) // i is not in scope
   {
       strcpy(currtime,timetoken);
   }
```

As a general rule, defer declaring variables until you absolutely need them.  It makes the code easier to read (variables in use tend to be close to the code using them) and less buggy (as shown above).

Hope this helps you get started!

Comment: Thanx but after making the above changes it shows 2 warnings stating that "(In function `main':)" , "(passing arg 1 of `localtime' makes pointer from integer without a cast )" and it shuts off automatically as usual without executing the program. I wrongly tagged the program as c++ when i have coded it in c,sry.

Answer (score 3):

Some problems with the posted code:

- This running beyond the end of the array:

  ```
  strcpy(schedtime,"15:25:00");
  ```

  as `schedtime` is declared as a `char[7]`, needs to be `char[9]` (8 characters plus null terminator).
- the first argument to `strtok()` is a `char*`, not a `char`:

  ```
  timetoken=strtok('\0'," ");
  ```

  You meant:

  ```
  timetoken=strtok(NULL," ");
  ```
- there is no check that `timetoken` is not null or to ensure that it will fit into `currtime`:

  ```
  if(i==3)
  {
      strcpy(currtime,timetoken);
  }
  ```

  passing a null pointer to `strcpy()` will most almost certainly result in a segmentation fault ( http://ideone.com/bacOG ).

Answer (score 2):

This sequence is a [buffer overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow). You have scribbled over unrelated memory with the contents of your string, so *anything* can happen after this point. (Buffer overflows used to the be the most widely and easily exploited security problems.)

```
char schedtime[7];
strcpy(schedtime,"15:25:00");
```

You need to make sure `schedtime` is long enough to hold the entire string, including the ascii `NUL` byte at the end. `schedtime[9]` will suffice.

This is an odd way to write an infinite loop:

```
while(6!=9)
{
...
}
```

More idiomatic is `while (1)` or `for (;;)`. Stick with those, they make it far easier for others to read your code.

There are probably other mistakes in the details of your code, but there is a much larger fault in the *design* of the problem; you assume that running `sleep(1)` in an infinite loop and checking the string value of the time against a target time will eventually compare *true* -- this is an incorrect assumption. A process that goes to sleep for one second may be woken up *after* the appointed time has already passed -- your process may sleep right through the 1000 miliseconds when your condition could evaluate to *true*.

Far better would be to check the current time against the desired time, figure out how many seconds that is away, and `sleep()` for the entire duration. Unless your task is woken by a signal first, it'll be within a second of the desired time.

Answer (score 1):

You are copying more data into `schedtime` than you allocated:

```
strcpy(schedtime,"15:25:00");
```

The string copied is 9 characters long, you have space for 7.  This might not be a problem in itself, but if the memory is arranged in a way that `localtimptr` is involved, the terminating null character will not be there when calling `printf()` with `scheduletime`, possibly touching memory that is not allocated for your process, thus ending in error